# Showing HTML in android

Tags: android, html

I am using a TextView to show some text I have formatted from HTML:

```
Spanned s = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.disclaimer));
tvDisclaimer.setText(s);
```

The text is in the `strings.xml` using CDATA:

```
<string name="disclaimer">
    <![CDATA[
    <p>blablabla</p>
    <ul>
      <li>foo
      <li>bar
    </ul> 
    ]]>
</string>
```

The point now, is that the whole thing crashes with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in `Choreographer`. It works for some simple HTML, but at some point, I only have to add one character (ø) to have it crash. Removing the character makes it work.

If `Html.fromHtml()` is not the way to go, what could I use to get some decent rich text in my app?

Comment: Are you using the html char code or directly the char ?

Comment: Directly the char. But in other places, the char works fine.

Comment: Since `<ul>` and `<li>` are not supported by `Html.fromHtml()`, you have bigger problems.

Comment: @CommonsWare, okay thanks. Too bad that is not found in the docs. Plus, I would like to have a HtmlNotSupportedException or something alike. Or at least an exception in Html.fromHtml. Now I get some strange error in a strange place. /rant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. As already stated in the comments, the `Html.fromHtml()` method only supports a limited set of HTML. It can be accomplished by using a `WebView`:

```
    WebView wvDisclaimer = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvDisclaimer);
    wvDisclaimer.loadDataWithBaseURL("about:blank", 
            getString(R.string.disclaimer), "text/html", "utf-8", "about:blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by using below codes:

```
<string name="disclaimer">
<![CDATA[
<p>blablabla</p>
    <br>&#8226; &nbsp;foo
    <br>&#8226; &nbsp; bar
]]>
</string>
```

Hope it helps.